Force a connection to a site through Chrome by typing `thisisunsafe` giving this message "Sorry, protonvpn.com has been blocked by your network admini
How to fix this message after typing thisisunsafe through Chrome

Sorry, ..........com has been blocked by your network administrator.


Are you on a company domain, or is this your own computer on your own link?

You cannot; Your Administrator has blocked the website.  Unless you are an administrator, you cannot unblock it.  thisisunsafe is only the password used to bypass a specific TLS certificate error. That password is only for HSTS errors.

You're using the wrong tool for this job:
thisisunsafe is specifically for SSL errors thrown by your browser. It only impacts blocks and protections occurring within the browser itself.
The message you're getting "...has been blocked by your network administrator" is not coming from inside the browser, and so telling your browser "thisisunsafe" doesn't mean anything. Your browser already thinks its going to the site you asked for: it sent the request, and controlling devices on the network said "this is the site you asked for" and returned that block message.
So, you'll need to determine what is actually blocking your traffic.

If this is a business computer on a business network: Stop. Talk with your IT folks.
If this is a personal computer on a personal network: it is probably your main network device on which is enabled some sort of filtering or protection. If its your own network, you'll need to look through the router settings. If it's someone else's network, talk with them.


I'd guess being inside the big red country might also have something similar appear.

Possibly. I don't know what their message would be, but something similar would likely be possible.

Thanks music2myear for your explanation.! "If its your own network, you'll need to look through the router settings." Could you explain more about how to look through the router settings to solve this problem please?

That is a different question and can have it's own place here, but... When you ask it, note that we will need to know the precise and specific router brand, model, and software version. Also, you should do research, using your routers name and info, on filtering, and you'll probably easily find the official documentation for the built in filtering tool.
